# Is there a utility you would use to create wordlists from directories and files?

Tags: password-cracking, wordlist

I have a home directory and a gpg file I am attempting to brute force. Is there a utility that you know that will recursively create wordlist from directives and file contents?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crunch` for that:

> `-q filename.txt` Tells  crunch  to  read  filename.txt  and  permute
> what is read.  This is like the -p option except it gets the input
> from file ‐name.txt

[crunch manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/crunch.1.html)

Comment: You don't even state what the switch/command is.

Comment: For this command to work, you need to populate the file with the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

You're much better off using the major cracking tools' built-in ability to ingest entire directories. For hashcat, just use a directory name where you would use a filename. Add rules with -r.

Assuming that you have at least one supported GPU, this will be much more efficient than using Crunch because the rules are applied to the wordlists on GPU, which is much faster than applying the rules externally with Crunch and then piping the results to hashcat.